# Mapping between pseudosphere and breather segments

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mapping-space

The pseudospheres $(K=-1)$ shown contain two  cuspidal edge boundaries  and appear to admit isometric mapping between 1) the surface of revolution through an expansion/contraction deformation in orthogonal directions and 2) a single segment or nappe of a breather.

If asymptotic lines are used in parametrization on either surface they run tangential to cuspidal edges ( rhombic differential shell of a fishing net or Chebyshev net becomes very narrower at edges). If $K$ is conserved in isometric mappings, then isometry is not necessarily valid. In this case we may term it as *isolineal mapping* where lengths are invariant, but angles change.

[image: Breather, its soliton segments, rotational pseudosphere]

With a cut along a meridian of a rubbery surface of revolution between cusp ridged ends A and B in a segment and pulling on the narrow handles in center picture in opposite directions to infinite distances away from each other (after a surface self-intersection)... we can deform a single segment of rotational segment to a breather segment and vice-versa.

How do we connect Bäcklund transform with conventional symmetric parametrization?

Is it possible to define an isometric/ isolineal mapping between the two? If so, how may it be accomplished?

I could not connect pdes for example in reference [pseudosphere to sine-Gordon](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Geometric%20Origin%20of%20Sine-Gordon/Pseudosphere%20to%20Sine-Gordon.pdf) towards this end. Request all help in such an attempt.

Comment: Do you mind my asking why you ‘trademarked’ the photo?

Comment: Marking routine I do just for title /date reference in research. If it appeared that way, I am removing my name. This is a site I respect much.

Comment: I personally found it distracting when trying to read through your post; a good rule of thumb is to post as little about yourself as possible (minimize usage of ‘I’, ‘me’, etc.) and as much about the math as possible. (Instead of saying ‘I have found that…’ use phrases like ‘We have that…’ etc.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, editing...

Comment: What's your definition of the/a pseudosphere and the/a breather?

Comment: http://xahlee.info/surface/a/Pseudospherical_Surfaces.pdf Solutions  of Sine-Gordon pde $ \alpha_{st}= \sin \alpha $ define Chebychev  asymptotic lines. Differential lengths same, scissoring angle varies.(iso-lineal map?) They are also model solition equations. I am curious to recognize diffeomorphism between  a single branch of a multi soliton breather surface of the  given center mage with  rotational  hyperbolic  pseudosphere surface ( whose ode of meridian is $  \cos^{2}\phi +r^2= m^2, \quad \phi$ slope, $r$ cylindrical coordinates radius, $m>1$ real constant), third image.

Comment: At the moment isometric mapping is my image based guess only.

Comment: All definitions should be in your question. What you wrote is nowhere close to a definition.

Comment: Odes are sufficient I thought...but  can you please help me, with some hints? Thanks.